# Time delay in simulink

Tags: time, delay, simulink

I am working on my graduation project. It is a digital protection relay which  trips if the measured value exceeds a specific value. It must trip after a time delay. We use texas instrument kit and simulink to build the program.

[image]

My problem is how to make a time delay so that i can delay the trip signal with predetermined time. The attached image shows aport of the program
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement that by creating a counter (integrator). For example the counter increments (counter_value +=.001) by one each millisecond. Your trip delay is 1.54 s then you compare (>=) the value of the counter to your trip delay.

The counter is activated and reset by the boolean input signal that you want to delay.

I dont have Simulink installed. Therefore i cant give you a picture, and i think pseudocode would not help much either.